# Install Git separately from Xcode

Tags: xcode, macos, git

Firstly apologies if this is a really simple question but Git is absolutely brand new to me.  Basically I've been dabbling with a bit of iOS development for a little while and now have a project idea that I want to start working on and for the first time I'm planning on putting this into source control.

Now I know Xcode 4 has some Git integration but I've spotted a couple of posts that suggest the integration isn't that great and it's better to do it the command line way.

So, I've been following instructions here http://git-scm.com/book/en/Getting-Started-Installing-Git and I've downloaded version 1.7.10.3 for Mac and ran the install.

However when I run git --version I get version 1.7.4.4 which is the version that was installed with Xcode I assume?

My question is, how do I make use of my new version 1.7.10.3?  The plan is to learn to use Git via command tools and set up a central repository on a server I have at home, then have local copies on my laptop.

As I say I'm really new to this, so a quick step by step idiots guide would be helpful.  I have searched and tried to find details here and on google but other than the suggestion to use Git outside of Xcode I've not found out exactly how to do it.

Any advice, or links to a decent tutorial that covers this would be very much appreciated.

**Update:**

I've changed the path to the new path in .bash_profile (/usr/local/git/bin) and now get git version 1.7.7.5 (Apple Git-26).  This still appears to be the wrong version (although this could be me being dense).  I downloaded the installer for OSX from the above link. Should I be doing something else.  I want to play around with the command line tools so I can get a proper understanding

**Update 2:**

I'm now also trying MacPorts as recommended in the article.  This seems to be downloading a lot more than just Git though

Comment: have you tried running `which git`?  If you have more than one installed, you need to be sure the path is using the one you want

Comment: To my knowledge, Xcode does not include git, so as suggested, you probably have two different gits installed and your path is pointing to the original one.

Comment: I've just run which git and that points to /usr/bin/git... I now also have a version of git installed at /usr/local/git/bin (I think).  I've never installed git previously and my understanding from other posts is that Xcode 4 will install a version but I'm guessing it makes sense to use the later one.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Xcode installs git in /Applications/Xcode.app/... but if you run 'Install Command Tools' then git gets installed also in /usr/bin/git.  Xcode uses its private version in Xcode.app.  If you  installed git in /usr/local/git/bin then you need to include that directory in your PATH.  You should have a .bashrc file (or equivalent for whatever shell you are using).  Add

```
PATH=/usr/local/git/bin:$PATH     # your shell might use different syntax.
```

to that file 'rc' file.

Also, note that Xcode would allow you to accomplish your goal of setting up a remote at home while maintaining a local copy on your laptop.  Go to the Xcode 'organizer' and click 'repositories'. There you will find all your machine's Git repositories.  Choose one, select the 'remotes' folder and then '+' to add your home remote.  I use Xcode this way.

Comment: Hi, ok I've just added that to .bash_profile as recommended on another post and now get version 1.7.7.5 (Apple Git-26). This still seems to be a lower version.  I took the download from here http://git-scm.com/download/mac.  It does say it might be better to build it manually to get all the features but can't seem to find a step by step guide on how to do that

Comment: http://git-scm.com/download starts downloading 1.7.10.3 for me automatically when I click 'mac os x'

Comment: Yep that's the same for me... but when I run the installer from the download and run a --version command, it says something totally different.  Is that just a red herring?

Comment: I just unpacked the git-scm dmg file and used the installer: ebg@taiyo(5)$ /usr/local/git/bin/git --version  ==>>
git version 1.7.10.3  Also if you edited the .bash_profile, you'll need to log in again or to do 'source ~/.bash_profile' to have the new PATH stick.

Comment: Although not directly I've worked it out.  If I put the full path in, I too got the correct version (no idea where 1.7.7.5 is) but the instructions on another post were incorrect.  So the answer was that the path should be PATH=/usr/local/git/bin/:$PATH but another answer had it as PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/git/bin/.  I changed it and ran the version command on git without specifying the full path and the version is now coming up as correct.  Big thanks for helping me out

Comment: The PATH shell variable has lots of components to it.  The components in front take precedence (which is why my ordering worked!).

Comment: Great, thanks GoZoner that makes sense, again, your answers have been great and most importantly, understandable for me :-)

Comment: Yosemite 10.10.5, July 1st 2016 :: Deleted XCode and Git stopped working from command line. These painless instructions worked for me: http://blog.bobbyallen.me/2014/03/07/how-to-install-git-without-having-to-install-xcode-on-macosx/

Answer (score 1):

Credits goes to @GoZoner for the answer. I'm just summing up everything.

Download official git installer from : http://git-scm.com/download/mac

Install and add its directory to your path :

`echo "PATH=/usr/local/git/bin:\$PATH" >> ~/.bash_profile
source ~/.bash_profile`

Answer (score 0):

The best way is:

step 1:

Install homebrew on your mac this is the official website [Homebrew homepage](https://brew.sh/index_es)

From a Terminal prompt:

```
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

step 2:

From a terminal prompt

```
brew install git
```