# Install Git on Mac without Xcode

Tags: xcode, git, homebrew, macos-big-sur

I've been using windows for software development. I'm not aware of MacOS internals.
I'm aware that Xcode software is used to develop iOS/Mac apps but I don't need it.

For my usecase, I was able to install **intellij, Java, Docker, Minikube & Visual-Studio-Code** on my *Intel Mac with BigSur*...
I'm able to run simple micro-service with working DB in local in docker container.

But when I try to use Git I'm getting this issue:
`xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun`

I think this is related to Xcode. I didn't want to touch it,
so I tried to install Git by **brew**.

`brew install git` but got error
`Error: git 2.29.2 is already installed`

So I tried to do update
`brew upgrade git` but again got the below error again.

`xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun`

I also tried to remove Git to do a clean install
`brew remove git` and there was no error, but then I installed git with brew again and the same error.

**Is there a way to install Git without having Xcode ?**
I dont want to install unnecessary software on my machine, things which I don't need.

Comment: This one maybe: https://sourceforge.net/projects/git-osx-installer/ Found at https://git-scm.com/download/mac

Comment: tried, didn't work.... Had to install xCode command line... not sure about repercussions at this time.. but working for now...

Answer (score 16):

*Note that this is a plain copy of a previous answer of mine on [superuser.com](https://superuser.com/questions/322633/how-to-install-git-on-mac-without-xcode/1008164#answer-1008164).*

Here's a way to install git on Mac OS X without XCode.

Git's official web site provides an installer : http://git-scm.com/download/mac

After installing git, you also have to add its directory to your path :

```
echo "PATH=/usr/local/git/bin:\$PATH" >> ~/.bash_profile
source ~/.bash_profile
```

Adding the directory to the path will prevent Mac OS X from aksing you to install XCode each time you type `git` in the terminal.

Credits goes to [Bobby Allen](http://blog.bobbyallen.me/2014/03/07/how-to-install-git-without-having-to-install-xcode-on-macosx/) and to [GoZoner's answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10904774/install-git-separately-from-xcode#answer-10905031).

Answer (score 6):

What you need is not xcode but xcode command line tool which has a small download and running file space compared to xcode of 11GB download space and running space of 31GB

You can download it from apple at https://developer.apple.com/downloads/

Comment: git on Mac OSX (mine is Monterey 12.5.1) is asking to re-agree to the XCode license agreement, but there's no way to agree. The ask for license is broken it seems and now I cannot use git without agreeing to an 11 page license agreement for all of xcode.